# one svn account for each programmer?

Tags: svn

Should I have one SVN user for each programmer on the Ubuntu server?

Is this accomplished by using "htpasswd" 4 times for 4 programmers?

How do I couple all these users to same group so that I could modify file access specific for the SVN group and all its members?

Comment: Are you using Apache 2 with dav_svn? Also, this probably belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: You should ask the mods to merge your user accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be giving all committers individual credentials. Each developer should have their own account, so that changes can be [traced to a specific person](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html). Over time you'll get an accurate view of who best knows parts of code. As a bonus, when one person leaves the group, you don't have to change the password (lets pretend you would actually do that for the moment).

There's two parts two configuring this; Authentication and Authorization. **Authentication** is the process of determining identity. You can use htpasswd to do this, but it's better to integrate your existing password systems if possible. [mod-auth-external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) can likely do this for you.

The other part is **authorization**; determining who is allowed to access what. The easiest way is to use [SVN Authz](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz) and [path based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) to define a group.

For example, your authz file may look like:

```
[groups]
developers = alice, bob, carla, trudy

[repo1:/]
developers = rw

[repo2:/]
alice = rw
developers = r
```

Comment: Much more thorough answer than mine. I'll upvote tomorrow, I'm at my limit for today.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Each developer should have their own Apache username. Note they do not need a Unix user on the Ubuntu server. Just a different user created via htpasswd. If they are all in the same htpasswd file, they will be able to access the svn repo.

For more complicated permission management, look into [SVN Authz files](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a project such as [Subversion Admin](http://code.google.com/p/subversionadmin/) to manage all the access files for you.  It also allows you to easily setup the post-commit email notifications. As well as connect your server into an ldap or active directory system.